# How to set up cron to call php script - bash: */5: No such file or directory for setting cron job

Tags: cron, magento

we are trying to set up cron for magento site running in ubuntu server

we are trying following command :

```
*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php
```

but we are getting  error as below :

```
-bash: */5: No such file or directory
```

**Update 1**

[image]

**Update 2 - Error**

```
PHP Warning:  require(app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php on line 30

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php on line 30
```

**cron.php**

```
<?php


// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
$isShellDisabled = true;

try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
            }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
            $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
            $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            exit;
        }
    }

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What you've written isn't a *command* that you can enter in the shell - it's a *crontab entry* that should go in a special file, which you can edit using `crontab -e` (user crontab) or `sudo crontab -e` (root crontab)

Comment: @steeldriver please check updated question with error

Comment: If you have a follow-on question then please post it separately, rather than changing the original question - this is a Q&A site not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About cron**

Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) here

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like
>   computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software
>   environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to
>   run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals. It typically
>   automates system maintenance or administration..

Please check [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for more informations about cron

**View crontab**

To output/view the crontab of the current user

```
crontab -l
```

To view the crontab of another user you would need sudo permissions

```
sudo crontab -l -u nameOfOtherUser
```

**Edit crontab**

To edit your users crontab

```
crontab -e
```

or for another user via

```
sudo crontab -e -u nameOfOtherUser
```

**How your cron could look like**

The possible cron line using full path to php

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  -q /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php
```

or for debugging purposes as mentioned by @Brian

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  -q /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php > /var/www/html/sitename/cron-temp.log 2>&1
```

This writes a log file called `cron-temp.log` in `/var/www/html/sitename/`

**Regarding parameters**

-q = quiet mode

**Your todo**

- Edit your cron and add the new line which defines how often which script should be called
- Wait until the interval triggers and check the log file if you are using this option

Comment: it executed successfully, but cron job is still not working.

Comment: @spylh9999ggr: Please help us helping you by mentioning what you did. Otherwise its hard to follow ;) Please update your post above and tell us how you tested executing and how your crontab now looks like.

Comment: Temporarily @spylh9999ggr, you should append ' > /var/www/html/sitename/cron-temp.log 2>&1 ' to your cron entry, so it sends the output for your debugging/review.

Comment: please check question, i have tried like image in question

Comment: Please re-read my entire answer again. You are supposed to edit your crontab and add a new line to it. You are not supposed to enter the crontab-line directly into your terminal as command ;)

Comment: please check updated question with errors

Comment: Please update your post with the content of both... your crontab file and your cron.php.

Comment: please check updated question with cron.php code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you type this in a terminal ?
This is a cronjob definition, not a command.
This line has to go in /etc/crontab
The user is also missing...

I think you copy this from another site without really understanding how it works. If yes, read some documentation about cron...

Comment: please check question, i have tried like image in question